# Graph to model the order of different tasks in construction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have this question:

> During the construction of a house there are certain tasks that have
>   to be completed before another one can commence, e.g., the roof has to
>   be installed before work on electrical wiring or plumbing can begin.
>   How can a graph be used to model the different tasks during the
>   construction? Should the edges be directed or undirected? By analyzing
>   the graph model, how can we find tasks that can be done at any time?
>   Knowing the amount of time that each task takes, what do we need to
>   compute to find the minimum time necessary to build the whole house
>   (assuming enough resources are always available)?

Right off the bat, I know the the graph that depicts the ordered tasks should have directed edges, because the order is important. If we are trying to find the processes that can be done in any order, then we could use undirected edges. From there, though, I'm lost. It's talking about analyzing the graph model, but how am I supposed to know how many points to plot, or how to connect them? Any advice here? Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_graph

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to build a house, a good thing to use is the Gantt chart:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart

From a graph theory point of view:

- the graph is oriented (and loopless)
- the nodes stand for each task (ractangles of the gantt diagram)
- there is an arrow between i and j if i has to be done before j. Its length is the duration of task i.

Then, all becomes much clearer. You can see then that the longest path in your graph is the total duration of your project (house building). Different connected components from the graph can be done at the same time. You would start all tasks represented by nodes with no father at the same time, ...

Comment: Gantt charts aren't covered in this course, so I'm thinking that it's looking for some other type of graph. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Each vertex $v$ represents a task, while a (directed) edge $e = (v_1, v_2)$ represents that the $v_1$ task needs to be completed before the $v_2$ task. For finding the minimum time, we need to give each vertex a weight that represents the time needed to complete the corresponding task. With this construction, can you see how to analyze it as the problem asks?

Comment: Thank you. How do I know what weights to give the vertices, if that information is not provided? Am I supposed to be answering this question only in general terms?

Comment: That part is only needed when analyzing the minimum necessary time, and that part of the problem states "*Knowing* the amount of time that each task takes..."

Comment: So, in order to find the minimum time necessary, I would just assign weights to the vertices to represent time needed? What else would have to be done, though? This doesn't seem like that's all that the question is asking. Honestly, the question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: This just gives you the graph model - the question is also asking how you analyze that model to find tasks that can be done at any time and find the minimum time necessary to complete all tasks.

Comment: So, the vertices with the highest weights would be done first, while the ones with the lowest weights would be done last? And the ones with the same weight can be done done in any order?

Comment: No; you need to analyze the structure created by the edges.

Comment: But how do I create the structure without knowing how many edges and vertices to create?